# How do I use the Exchange Managed EWS API to find the appointments assigned to a Resource?

Tags: resources, exchange-server, exchangewebservices, ews-managed-api

I'm trying to get a list of all the appointments assigned to a resource.  Resource accounts can't be logged into, so I can't impersonate the accounts.

I can set up an admin account with delegate access to the resource accounts.  I've done this successfully, but it isn't allowing me to retrieve the appointments.

How can I query all the events in a folder of another account?

I'm probably just missing something simple in the docs, but I haven't figured it out yet.  Help!

Answer (score 0):

Look at [Using Impersonation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd633680%28v=EXCHG.80%29.aspx). If you follow all the advices and configure the exchange server corresponds to [Configuring Exchange Impersonation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb204095.aspx) you will be able to impersonate any user from which you know his email address instead of the password.